# How i can use @SWG\Parameter for multiple file upload?

Tags: yii2, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger for apidoc but I need parameter block for multiple files upload in sing parameter

```
     @SWG\Parameter(

          description="vMediaName[]", 
          in="formData",
          name="vMediaName[]",
          required=true,
          type="file",
          format="file",
      ),
```

can any body provide me solution ?

Comment: Do you need to upload a fixed number of files (e.g. 3 files) or an arbitrary number (array) of files? The former should be possible, the latter is not supported in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0.

Comment: not fixed number of files